# Consuming a Restful webservice with Java code

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jersey

I have the following REST service running on JBoss:

```
@POST
@Path("/postTest")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response PostTest(MyOwnUserData user)
{
    return Response.ok(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

In another program, I am trying to call this method with the following code:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String mainUrl = "http://localhost:8080/services/users/test/posTest";

    ResponseEntity<MyOwnUserData > n2 = null;
    RestTemplate n = new RestTemplate();

    MyOwnUserData u = new MyOwnUserData ();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    // This is needed to set the content-type header as application/json. The web service will throw a 415 Media Type unsupported if you dont set this.
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<MyOwnUserData> entity = new HttpEntity(u,headers);

    n2 = n.postForEntity(mainUrl,u, MyOwnUserData .class);

}
```

When I execute the second program it always gives `BAD_REQUEST`.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

JBOSS Log error at the moment of execution:

```
23:44:49,256 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) RESTEASY000100: Failed executing POST /test/posTest: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: RESTEASY001055: Cannot consume content type
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.Segment.match(Segment.java:118) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:34) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:328) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:45) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:328) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:45) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:328) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:45) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:328) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:375) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:368) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:349) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:191) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:124) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at ar.com.flexibility.app.filter.ApiOriginFilter.doFilterInternal(ApiOriginFilter.java:46) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
```

Comment: And what's the problem? What happens? What happens not?

Comment: What's in the `MyOwnUserData` class? Is it properly unserializable for the server? Have you set content-type header correctly? Are there any filters (servlet filters, jersey filters, whatever) in the mix on the server side which could be interfering with the request before it interacts with your resource?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
ResponseEntity<Response> n2 = null;
n2 = n.postForEntity(mainUrl,u, Response.class);
```

with

```
ResponseEntity<MyOwnUserData> n2 = null;
n2 = n.postForEntity(mainUrl,u, MyOwnUserData.class);
```

Comment: Now i get "resulted in 415 (Unsupported Media Type)"

Comment: Ok, in your service, return Response<String> and in you client: ResponseEntity<String> n2 = null;
n2 = n.postForEntity(mainUrl,u, String.class);

Comment: There is no such type as "Response<String>"

Comment: Sorry, it's ResponseEntity<String>.

Comment: Same problem :S

Comment: in you service, do you return ResponseEntity<String>?

Comment: Yes, i changed it but the problem remains. I belive the third answer in this post is nearly to be correct but i don't figure out how to make the HttpEntity.

Answer (score 0):

Can use

```
 UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8080/test/postTest");

 n.postForEntity(builder.build().encode().toUri(), u, MyOwnUserData.class)
```

Comment: Same error :S . "resulted in 415 (Unsupported Media Type)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
// Set the message converter so as to enable marshalling/demarshalling for json
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()));

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
// This is needed to set the content-type header as application/json. The web service will throw a 415 Media Type unsupported if you dont set this.
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<MyOwnUserData> entity = new HttpEntity<MyOwnUserData>(u,headers);
Response response = restTemplate.postForObject(mainUrl, entity, Response.class);
```

Comment: Little problem, I think you mean "HttpEntity<MyOwnUserData>" instead of "HttpEntity<String>", but i eclipse gives an error when you try to set a type to "HttpEntity".

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected that in my answer. And it should work. Are you sure you are using this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#HttpEntity-T-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-

Comment: Thanks! We made and advance but know i get error 415, even with the setContentType setence.

Comment: Can you enable the http wire logs and share the request that is being sent to the web service? My hunch is that your MyOwnUserData object is not being marshalled as json correctly. Logs would confirm if that is true or not

Comment: Yes, check the error at the editted question, buy you can see it is bassically the object is sent and returned in the same way.

Comment: You need to configure a message converter with rest template to take care of marshalling/unmarshalling. Added that in my answer (setMessageConverters part).

Comment: MMM Can not use thar parameter, "The method setMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>) in the type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (List<MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter>)"

Comment: That's weird. Can you cross-check the imports? If that doesnt result in anything; please share the java file along with the spring version

Comment: Yes, you can see the imports at the question. I am looking for spring version (i started this project with some code that is not mine).

Comment: This is probably some kind of project/dependency configuration issue. Try replacing MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter with MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter (This is the predecessor version of the former)

Comment: Same problem :( . Where can i see spring version?